# Open a form from a report and vice versa

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

So I have 2 projects, well a few more than that. But 1 project or multiple are forms and the other is a DevExpress XtraReport. I need to be able to open the report from the form and open the form from the report. Obviously there is a circular dependency, so any way around this? I am looking into using an Interface but am not knowledgeable enough to actually implement it.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to open a form from the Report? click on the some report element/control? or clicking on some ribbon button?